# Bank login dialog in an iframe when you shop online, how does it work?

Tags: security, authentication, iframe, onlinebanking

I was shopping online and at the time of payment, a login dialog from my bank appears in an iframe, I filled my details and the the online shop page let me go on with the purchase.

How does it work? I guess:

1. The online shop shows you the page with an iframe pointing to your
   bank login widget.
2. You fill the login details and the bank authenticate you.

Now, how the bank now pass information to the online shop site to tell them you can go on?

Because the login is in an iframe, and as far as I know what happen in the iframe cannot affect the container page. So once you are authenticated in your bank, how the bank tell the online shop page "it's good, go on" ?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a typical checkout situation there is as you can imagine a lot that goes on behind the scenes. But typically in this scenario, one would include with the request to the payment provider (i.e. PayPal, SagePay (formerly Protx), DataCash) a return success URL and return error URL. Typically a handler of some description on the ecommerce site would receive a callback from the payment provider (i.e not the iframe) once you have successfully completed authentication with your bank.

Comment: Right, but once that the ecommerce site has the positive response from my bank, how the page in my browser moves ahead or knows that I'm authenticated?

Comment: maybe some hidden javascript checking cookies or posting request to a webservice.
I once used an ASelect Agent / filter software to provide single sign on, this software had a windows service running in the background and was able to set crossdomain cookies. In the website i could read this cookie to get specific user info. The bank probably uses similar methods

Comment: cross domain cookieS? how could that be possible?

Answer (score 1):

The website could have some webservices or other services running in the background handling the bank response and setting some sort of cookie or session for the site and loading another page.